# post two ajax request into two different server file on modal display

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How to send two **id's** using ajax and jquery at the same time when **bootstrap modal** is loaded.

Am working on a project, when a modal load it has to send two ajax request to the server and append the returned data to the **modal-body** input text.

Below are the codes that send the requests,

```
    $('#myPayment').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var guestID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('guest-id');
    var bID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('b-id');
    var bgID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('bg-id');
    var booking_date = $(e.relatedTarget).data('booking-date');
    var room_rate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-rate');
    var room_price = $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-price');
    var room_currency = $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-currency');

    $.ajax({
            url: "inc/get_room_rate_name.php",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'curr_room_rate' : $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-rate')},
            success: function(value) {
                $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="room_rate"]').val(value);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/get_currency.php",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'curr_currency' : $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-currency')},
            success: function(value) {
                var data = value.split('-');
                var room_currency = data[1];
                $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="currency"]').val(room_price + " " +room_currency);
            }
        });
    //populate the textbox
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="first_name"]').val(guestID);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="b_id"]').val(bID);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bg_id"]').val(bgID);
    //$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="room_rate"]').val(room_rate);
    //$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="currency"]').val(room_data);
});
```

Comment: CAn you show your code?

Comment: What's not working? If you need things done in a particular order or based upon the result of the previous, then look into the pub/sub model.

Comment: The codes return data to the second ajax call only .

Comment: You can send multiple data by using `data : { curr_currency: $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-currency'), curr_room_rate: $(e.relatedTarget).data('room-currency') },`

Comment: Your correct but, the two id's has to be posted on different php files.

Comment: Not sure what's missing here, you are already sending two different AJAX requests each with different data and each to a different endpoint which sounds like exactly what you're asking how to do